# Where did this claim about the Egpytian Theban army come from?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt

In this old [Locomotive Engineers Journal](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Locomotive_Engineers_Journal/vhESAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), there is a short discussion of ancient vs modern army sizes. The writer gives a list of very large ancient armies. Most of the items on the list have easy enough sources. For example:

1. Xerxes led 2,641,610 combatants and as many non-combatants. Invasion of Greece, Herodotus.
2. Hamilcar led 2,000 ships and 3,000 smaller vessels, together with 300,000 soldiers. Battle of Himera, Diodorus Siculus. There is a typo here: 2,000 should be 200.
3. Timur had 1,600,000 soldiers against Bayezid, who had 1,400,000. Battle of Ankara, Johann Schiltberger.

However, one of the items on the list I couldn't recognize:

> "The city of Thebes had 100 gates and could sent out at each gate 10,000 fighting men and 200 chariots - in all, 1,000,000 men and 20,000 chariots."

This is obviously referring to Egyptian Thebes, but searching for this number only reveals a similar list. In the [War Scrap Book of Matilda Gage](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_War_Scrap_Book_of_Matilda_Joslyn_Gag/PHJ9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1), a similar list of vast armies in ancient times is contained:

- Some items in the journal's list, like the Battle of Ankara, are omitted.
- Other items, like the Battle of Cannae (80,000 infantry, 6,000 cavalry, Polybius), are only present on Gage's list.
- In both lists, the claim about Thebes is repeated, and is the first item on the list.

Since these are mostly famous battles, it is possible the two lists are totally unrelated. They seem to be organized in loose chronological order, so it seems the claim about Thebes should be in very ancient Egyptian times. But I cannot find where it comes from.

Comment: Book 9 of the Iliad has 100 gates with 200 chariots per gate, at Egyptian Thebes.

Comment: Ancient sources seem to typically be much more into trying to impress the listener/reader than into preserving a precise census of forces. The first city in the world to reach 1 million residents probably didn't happen until the 2nd century BC, and it wasn't Thebes.

Comment: @kimchi lover Does it future 1,000,000 soldiers as well?

Comment: @T.E.D. That is a common modern impression, but I am not sure I agree with it. Either way, the question was not whether the number was accurate, but where it came from.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/History_of_Civilisation/dZtYAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22from+each+gate%22+thebes&pg=PA37&printsec=frontcover talks about 1,000,000 as an exaggeration by Strabo and/or Pomponius Mela, but I have not verified his sources.

Comment: and the discussion at https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Origin_of_Laws_Arts_and_Sciences/owq9snGdK4UC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=thebes+hundred+gates+million+mela&pg=PA139&printsec=frontcover  has more precise references, which I have not verified.

Comment: I have found the source. Strabo, Book XVII, Chapter 46. It repeats Homer's words, then claims that certain Egyptian Kings maintained an army of 1,000,000 soldiers. However the army of 1,000,000 is in the context of the entire Egyptian state, not the single city of Thebes.

Comment: Tacitus, 2. 60 claims Thebes of old had 700,000 men of military age, which is an altogether different claim than the record of 700,000 soldiers.

Comment: Pomponius Mela, 1.60 records there were 100 gates in the city, or alternatively 100 palaces of great chiefs, and the each chief led 10,000 armed men.

Comment: Pomponius Mela, _De Chorographia_, book I, chap ix (https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101073028985&view=1up&seq=125&skin=2021&q1=effundere) has this calculation: 100 gates, times tens of thousands. See https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/300201.pdf for a discussion.

Comment: The pattern with all these claims is that the number of soldiers is either the total military manpower, not the standing army, or the entire army throughout. 1,000,000 or (700,000) military eligible men, or 1,000,000 soldiers in the entire empire, is very different from a single army of 1,000,000 men.

Comment: It looks like the population of Thebes couldn't have been more than 100k, and that's later in the Ancient era. All of Egypt itself bumped around between 3.5 and 5 million throughout all of recorded history up until the modern era. Having half the entire male population of Egypt hanging out with weapons inside of Thebes ready to go seems ... quite unlikely.

Comment: I was not questioning the veracity of this figure, though I do not think it as implausible as you do. Ancient population figures are very variable, estimates for Persia rang from 17 to 100 million for instance. Wikipedia takes the average, which gives an illusion of certainty, but the numbers are much more flexible. Pomp. Mela only claims there were 100 chieftains in Thebes, each of which had 10,000 soldiers they could, hypothetically, mobilize. It is not necessary to assume these soldiers all lived in Thebes, only they were under the command of lords in Thebes.

Comment: This is also a theoretical total for mass mobilization, not all maintained simultaneously and not all mobilized at once. If Egypt had population of say, five or 10 million people, a total hypothetical manpower of 1,000,000 soldiers is not that unreasonable. Polybius records a similar total for Italy, and many historians today support him.

Comment: What does "come from" mean, in the context of this particular question?

Comment: I am just looking for the source of the claim, which you have found. If you could post our discussion as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Homer, Egyptian  Thebes had 100 gates, each capable of issuing 200 horsemen with associated chariots and horses ([Iliad](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/6130/6130-h/6130-h.htm), book 9, as translated by Alexander Pope, ca. 1720):

> Not all proud Thebes’ unrivall’d walls contain,
> The world’s great empress on the Egyptian plain
> (That spreads her conquests o’er a thousand states,
> And pours her heroes through a hundred gates,
> Two hundred horsemen and two hundred cars
> From each wide portal issuing to the wars)

According to the Roman geographer [Pomponius Mela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomponius_Mela)'s  *De chorographia*
(book I, chap 9,  in a 1585 English [translation](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A07401.0001.001/1:3.9?rgn=div2;view=fulltext))

> ...Thebes, which
> hath (as is reported in Homer) a hundred Gates, or
> (as other saye) a hundred Pallaces, the houses of so many
> Princes, eche of which Pallaces (as the state of affayres
> required) was wont to send foorth ten thousande
> armed men.

More recently this exaggeration has been repeated in [fiction](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/6130/6130-h/6130-h.htm), where a character says

> "It is," said the Doctor of Sorbonne, "because the stock of faith has greatly decreased."
>
> A great deal was said about Thebes and its hundred gates, and of the million of soldiers that issued out of those gates with the twenty thousand chariots of war.
>
> "Shut the book there," said Mr. Andrew. "Since I have taken to reading, I beg to suspect that the same genius that wrote Garagantua, used of yore to write all the histories."

and in [nonfiction](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015073728894&view=1up&seq=139&skin=2021&q1=thebes)  by the same [author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaire)

> But, who can possibly believe, that through each of the hundred gates of Thebes, there went out two hundred chariots of war, and one hundred thousand combatants ? That would amount to twenty thousand chariots, and one million of soldiers; and, if we reckon one soldier to every five inhabitants, the amount of the population of this single city, would be five millions; in a country which is not so large as Spain or France

(I cannot explain the funny math involved with  100 times 100,000 equaling one million.)